# How can I make the black part transparent to show the white background？

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#myElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4a94cd, #fe49a6);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the black part transparent to show the background behind，The background won't always be white，maybe a picture，The color part is a gradient of the whole

Comment: The question is unclear.  The black sections are boxes which you are adding and which are set to black.  If you remove them or set the background to transparent, then you will see the gradient behind, but not white.  What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Change the id attribute to class for the div myBar and change the background to white.

We can target each of myBar elements using nth-child selector
.myBar:nth-child(1),.myBar:nth-child(2) and so on. I have added a sample below.

We can also use images as background by adding background-image property to the css definition.

```
#myElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4a94cd, #fe49a6);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.myBar:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}


----------
<div id="myElement">
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
  <div class="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing in another post of yours that you want to make a progress bar (you should mention these things to make it easier for others to answer with relevant answers). And you probably want to change the height dynamically or something with this one div (to simulate the progress).

You can use the css property `clip-path` to achieve the effect of alternating between your gradient and a transparent background:

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/999/360);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}

#myElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 320px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4a94cd, #fe49a6);
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,100% 0,100% 20px,0 20px,
    0 30px,100% 30px,100% 50px,0 50px,
    0 60px,100% 60px,100% 80px,0 80px,
    0 90px,100% 90px,100% 110px,0 110px,
    0 120px,100% 120px,100% 140px,0 140px,
    0 150px,100% 150px,100% 170px,0 170px,
    0 180px,100% 180px,100% 200px,0 200px,
    0 210px,100% 210px,100% 230px,0 230px,
    0 240px,100% 240px,100% 260px,0 260px,
    0 270px,100% 270px,100% 290px,0 290px,
    0 300px,100% 300px,100% 320px,0 320px
  );
}
```

```html
<!--
  I just added the container to show a background image behind
  the element with the clip-path
-->
<div class="container">
  <div id="myElement"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: clip path is not needed when you have pattern.

Comment: Could you show an example? I'm not that familiar with clip-path, so it could be nice with other solutions.

Comment: Oh you did, lol. Sorry

Comment: see my answer too

Comment: I saw, but saying "using divs will not work" is kinda wrong, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: if you are willing to write thooose many paths in clip-path then you can use divs instead but i was just saying using svg is more easier because you need not to worry about the positions

Comment: I'm just pointing out that saying *"if you are willing to write thooose many paths in clip-path then you can use divs"* is definitely not the same as saying *"using divs will not work"*.

Answer (score 0):

- **You can create it easily using svg masking technique because using divs will not work**
- **As you will see on running the snippet that the image is behind the svg but looks very clear as the black part is now transparent.**

```css
#myElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="50" height="300" id="myElement">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient xl=0 x2=0 y1=0 y2=1 id="Gradient">
        <stop stop-color="#fe49a6" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="#4a94cd" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
      <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x=0 y=0 width=50 height=20 fill="#999" />
      </pattern>
      <mask id="mask-gradient" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="300">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="300" fill="url(#pattern)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect id="rect1" fill=url(#Gradient) x="0" y="0" width="50" height="300" mask="url(#mask-gradient)" />
  </svg>
  </div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667400104714-53da4894bf18?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for mask

```css
#myElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4a94cd, #fe49a6);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(0deg,#0000 10px, #000 0) 0 0/100% 10%;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
</div>
```